# Exclude pages in indexed search

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a TYPO3 6.2.31 instance. How can I exclude pages from the search?

And if they are already indexed how can I remove them from index?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your search engine you could use the flag "exclude from search" in the pages properties (your search engine should respect this flag).

Removing pages from an index normaly needs a rebuild of the index.
Some search engines check and respect visibility at the time of search, but as your pages still are available the finding will not be removed from results for you.

Disabling indexing based on the field `no_search` ("exclude from search"):

```
[globalVar page|no_search = 1]
page.config.index_enable = 0
[global]
```

Comment: I use indexed_search

Comment: AFAIK `indexed_search` respects the `no_search` field. But you also can switch off indexing based on this field with a little bit of typoscript. (I enhanced my answer)

Comment: I not want to disable indexed_search for all pages. only for specific ones. So I have to replace page with the Id?

Comment: the condition queries the field no_search in the pages record. Depending on the setting of the current page indexed_search is disabled. Assuming it is enabled globaly.

Comment: My indexed_search cache is beeing flooded with different versions of the same page (by injected L- and cHash-Params), assuming they are caused by an earlier version of the page in Googles cache. I think the only way to get rid of this is flushing the search-cache and using the above typoscript?

Comment: have you configured the valid options for the L parameter? `config.linkVars := addToList(L(0-3))`